# My vite proxy is not making request to the targeted url

Tags: reactjs, proxy, vite

I have a client using react (port 3000) and a server (port 8080). They are both running on local host. I want to use vite proxy to send cookie from the server to my client. But my request keep being sent to port 3000
This is my config

```
  server: {
    port:3000,
    host:true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws:true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
      },
    }
  }
```

and i make request like this

````
const request=await fetch('/api/hello')```

But i keep getting this error
````

GET http://localhost:3000/api/hello 404 (Not Found)